# Scrapy - Scrape multiple URLs using results from the first URL

Tags: python, scrapy

1. I use Scrapy to scrape data from the first URL.
2. The first URL returns a response contains a list of URLs.

So far is ok for me. My question is how can I further scrape this list of URLs? After searching, I know I can return a request in the parse but it seems only can process one URL.

This is my parse:

```
def parse(self, response):
    # Get the list of URLs, for example:
    list = ["http://a.com", "http://b.com", "http://c.com"]
    return scrapy.Request(list[0])
    # It works, but how can I continue b.com and c.com?
```

May I do something like that?

```
def parse(self, response):
    # Get the list of URLs, for example:
    list = ["http://a.com", "http://b.com", "http://c.com"]

    for link in list:
        scrapy.Request(link)
        # This is wrong, though I need something like this
```

Full version:

```
import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "mySpider"
    allowed_domains = ["x.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://x.com"]

    def parse(self, response):
        # Get the list of URLs, for example:
        list = ["http://a.com", "http://b.com", "http://c.com"]

        for link in list:
            scrapy.Request(link)
            # This is wrong, though I need something like this
```

Comment: Is there anything wrong if you do?

Comment: @HuguesFontenelle The first one work, but I want to loop the list and request each URL in the list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the yield statement:

```
def parse(self, response):
    # Get the list of URLs, for example:
    list = ["http://a.com", "http://b.com", "http://c.com"]

    for link in list:
        request = scrapy.Request(link)
        yield request
```

Comment: If anyone else comes across this and still has issues (as I did), the callback that scrapy.Request uses will default to the original parse function. You can set a different callback function by passing it into ```scrapy.Request(link,callback=newCallback)```

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose, you need to subclass `scrapy.spider` and define a list of URLs to start with. Then, Scrapy will automatically follow the links it finds.

Just do something like this:

```
import scrapy

class YourSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "your_spider"
    allowed_domains = ["a.com", "b.com", "c.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://a.com/",
        "http://b.com/",
        "http://c.com/",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        # do whatever you want
        pass
```

You can find more information on the [official documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html?highlight=scrape#our-first-spider) of Scrapy.

Comment: I don't know what URLs are inside the list and the list is not static. First I need to run the scrapy to get the list. How can I do this?

Comment: You indicate in your question that you want to further scrape the list of URLs found in the web page pointed by the first URL. But Scrapy will do this automatically for you. It will follow each URL it finds, you do not need to get this list of URLs. So I am not sure to well understant your need.

Comment: I updated my question with more code, hope it will be clearer. I need to start with `x.com`. After that, I get a response and I extract a list of URLs from it. I need to scrape these URLs in the list. I don't know what are inside the list and the content of the list will change over time. I am new to Scrapy, hope I don't make silly question.

Answer (score 0):

```
# within your parse method:

urlList = response.xpath('//a/@href').extract()  
print(urlList) #to see the list of URLs 
for url in urlList:
    yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)
```

This should work